# Apps I can install on Elementary OS

Tags: release-juno, ubuntu, thirdpartyapps

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm thinking of switching to Elementary. The only thing that keeps holding me back is the fact that (as I understood) not every ubuntu app is compatible with Elementary. Is it true? Am I going to have any problems with installing software I use on Ubuntu(Like IntelliJ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Not true (Is there a posibility [one in a million] that an app made for bionic doesn't run on juno, yes maybe, but the normal is that any made for bionic will run)

eOS [release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno) is based on Ubuntu 18.04, you can use any app that is designed to `bionic`, in fact we use those repos to install [thirdpartyapps](/questions/tagged/thirdpartyapps) where the repo owner doesn't have a specific eOS version but a Ubuntu one

Besides you can install [IntelliJ](https://snapcraft.io/intellij-idea-ultimate) in any distro that can use snapd and eOS can

You only need to install `snapd`

https://docs.snapcraft.io/installing-snapd/6735

---

https://snapcraft.io/intellij-idea-ultimate

https://snapcraft.io/search?category=developers